# GLTF isn't moving; it seems to stand perfectly still

Tags: three.js, gltf

This isn’t letting me adjust the position through the group or when I try changing the knight scenes position itself. Any idea as to why? It seems like buggy behavior but maybe I am doing something wrong.

```js
export const startLocalPlayer = (scene) => {
  const { knightScene } = getKnightClone();
  group.add(knightScene);

  scene.add(group);
  group.position.y = 4;
};
```

and

```js
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
import { AnimationMixer } from "three";
import Store from "../../store/store";
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

let gltf;

export const loadKnight = () => {
  loader.load(
    "/assets/KnightCharacter.glb",
    function (_gltf) {
      gltf = _gltf;

      gltf.scene.scale.multiplyScalar(0.5);

      Store.finishedLoadingAsset();
    },
    function (xhr) {},
    function (error) {
      console.log("An error happened");
    }
  );
};

export const getKnightClone = () => {
  let knightScene = gltf.scene.clone();
  let theMixer = new AnimationMixer(gltf.scene);
  let idleClip = theMixer.clipAction(gltf.animations[0]);
  let runningClip = theMixer.clipAction(gltf.animations[3]);

  return { knightScene, idleClip, runningClip, theMixer };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> let knightScene = gltf.scene.clone();

Clone your asset like so:

```js
import * as SkeletonUtils from 'three/examples/jsm/utils/SkeletonUtils.js';

// ...

const knightScene = SkeletonUtils.clone( gltf.scene );
```

`Object3D.clone()` does not properly handle skinned meshes yet. A complete demo that shows the usage of `SkeletonUtils.clone()` can be viewed here: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_multiple